# Регулярное выражение поиск от и до. Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, замена

Есть такой код:

```
{
version 0
1.000000
0.835000
0.190000
}
{
version 1
    diffuse_cube = diffuse.dds
    specular_cube = Art.dds
    hor_angle = 3.141590
    vert_angle = 0.364425
    env_brightness = 0.21
    attenuation = 0.0357142857142857
    water = 0.107142857142857
}
false
0.004015
""
1
    "FogExp" "-346.250000 2817.500000 0.133250 4.123750 0.391750 0.325000 0.325000 "
false

{
version 0
1.000000
0.835000
0.190000
}

{
version 1
    iveness = 0.050000
    wind = 0.226195
    swell = 0.400000
    period = 0.046286
}
```

Задача найти и удалить все блоки version 1

```
{
version 1
}
```

Исключая блоки version 0

```
{
version 0
}
```

Пока что дошел до такого выражения:
"version 1.*?[}]"
Но мне надо также захватить и верхнюю фигурную скобку.
Код в блоках может быть совершенно разным, но "version 1" всегда есть.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте —

```
\{\Rversion 1[^\}]*\}
```

Comment: Да действительно находит должным образом, спасибо.

Comment: А можно ли как-то еще застраховать на случай если код будет в таком виде "{version 0}" в одну строку? \R это я так понимаю перевод каретки, возможно ли как-то указать что любой символ?

Comment: Поставьте после \R вопросительный знак, и будут также удаляться `"{version 1}"`.